# MassTransit is publishing to the wrong endpoint

Tags: c#, masstransit

I have a C# application that reads from one Azure service bus (external), and publishes to a different Azure service bus (internal).

In my publish class, the constructor accepts `IPublishEndpoint`, which is used when publishing the message:

```
IPublishEndpoint endpoint;
...
await endpoint.Publish(message, cancellationToken);
```

The type of `endpoint` is: `massTransit.Context.ConsumeContextScope<ExternalServiceBus.Messages.IDeviceChanged>`

Which is the context that the message was received on, not the one it should be published on.  I believe this is causing the message to be sent back to the external bus, but it then fails to publish because there isn't an endpoint for that type of message.

I can't replace IPublishEndpoint with IBusControl because IBusControl creates a new DI scope to publish from, and I need data from the external consumer filters to pass to the internal publish filters.

How can I get the correct (internal) publish context?

Comment: Are you using [multi-bus](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/multibus.html)?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using MultiBus, `IPublishEndpoint` will always default to the normal `IBus` instance. I'm not entirely sure if the current scope will be used (it should, but I haven't verified it for your scenario), but you can get the specific `IPublishEndpoint` for another bus instance using that bus interface type as key and depending upon:

```cs
public class SomeConsumer :
    IConsumer<SomeMessage>
{
    public SomeConsumer(Bind<IInternalBus, IPublishEndpoint> publishEndpoint)
    {
        _publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint.Value;
    }
}
```

You can replace `IInternalBus` with any bus interface type (including `IBus` for the default bus).

Comment: That works.  Thanks Chris.